# Get run-time of each number in a Fibonacci sequence

Tags: c, time

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

void printFibonacci(int n) {    
    static int n1 = 0, n2 = 1, n3;    
    if (n > 0) {    
        n3 = n1 + n2;    
        n1 = n2;    
        n2 = n3;    
        printf("%d ", n3);    
        printFibonacci(n - 1);    
    }    
}

int main() {
    int n;
    struct timespec start, stop;
    double total_time;
    
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &start);
    printf("Enter the number of elements: ");    
    scanf("%d", &n);    
    printf("Fibonacci Series: ");    
    printf("%d %d ", 0, 1);    
    printFibonacci(n - 2);
    
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &stop);
    total_time = (stop.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) * 1e9;
    total_time = (total_time + (stop.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec)) * 1e-9;
    printf("\nTime taken for each sequence: %lf", total_time);
    return 0; 
}
```

This C program above has the user enter an integer, and the program will then output the Fibonacci sequence. What I am trying to do is to get the run-time of each number in the Fibonacci sequence down to the nanosecond. So far my attempt has been to use the `clockgettime()` function to get the start and stop time of the `fibonacci` function. However, that only outputs the total time the function took instead of how long each individual sequence took. How would I fix this code so I would get each individual sequence time instead?

For example, if the user inputs 12 the output I desire would look like this, where each sequence time is displayed:

```
Enter the number of elements: 12        
Fibonacci Series: 0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89           
Time taken for each sequence: 0.1023, 0.2024, 0.3025, 0.7024, 0.9323, 0.12023, 0.78923, 0.6723, 0.12323, 0.9033, 0.34523, 0.123423
```

Comment: Surely you don't want to time your `scanf` or even `printf`

Comment: `printFibonacci` needs to store a new clocktime at each level of recursion into something like an array.

Comment: Better serves if you measure how much time user takes to input correct Fibonacci numbers in order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As coded in the question, you compute the time for the whole sequence, including the time it takes the user to enter the number and the time it takes `printf` to output the values. This is meaningless.

Furthermore, you multiply the number of seconds by 10<sup>9</sup> but then divide the number of nanoseconds by 10<sup>9</sup> too: you should do one or the other but not both.

If you want to time the computation of each number, you should retrieve the clock just before the addition of the 2 previous numbers an immediately after the 3 assignments, retrieve the clock again. Trying to clock such a simple operation is quite difficult: `clock_gettime()` is not the right tool for this, you will more likely just measure the overhead of `clock_gettime`, the imprecision of the `CLOCK_REALTIME`, possibly polluted by asynchronous processes interrupting your program as you measure `CLOCK_REALTIME` instead of the current process' runtime. You probably should use `clock()` instead, but the measurements are likely to be insignificant.
Intermediary timings should be stored in a `static` array for `main` to print them.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MAX_TIMINGS 100
static double timings[MAX_TIMINGS];
static int timing_index = 2;

void printFibonacci(int n) {    
    static int n1 = 0, n2 = 1, n3;    
    if (n > 0) {  
        struct timespec start, stop;
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &start);
        n3 = n1 + n2;    
        n1 = n2;    
        n2 = n3;    
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &stop);
        if (timing_index < MAX_TIMINGS) {
            timings[n] = (stop.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) * 1e9 +
                         (stop.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec);
        }
        printf("%d ", n3);
        printFibonacci(n - 1);
    }
}

int main() {
    int i, n;
    double total_time = 0;
    
    printf("Enter the number of elements: ");    
    scanf("%d", &n);    
    printf("Fibonacci Series: ");    
    printf("%d %d ", 0, 1);    
    printFibonacci(n - 2);
    printf("\n");
    printf("Time taken for each number:");
    for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        printf(" %.0fns", timings[i]);
        total_time += timings[i];
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("Total time: %.0fns\n", total_time);
    return 0; 
}
```

Output:

```
Enter the number of elements: 20
Fibonacci Series: 0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144 233 377 610 987 1597 2584 4181
Time taken for each number: 0ns 0ns 0ns 0ns 0ns 0ns 0ns 0ns 0ns 0ns 0ns 0ns 0ns 0ns 0ns 0ns 0ns 0ns 0ns
Total time: 0ns
```

Unsurprisingly, all timings are null. Measuring the time for each number for your sequential generator is meaningless.

Conversely, timings are significant for the classic recursive implementation where many recursive calls are involved for even moderately large arguments.

Here is a more classic example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

unsigned long long fib(int n) {
    if (n < 2)
        return n;
    else
        return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
}

int main() {
    int i, n;
    double total_time = 0;

    printf("Enter the number of elements: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1)
        return 1;
    double timings[n + 1];
    printf("Fibonacci Series:");
    for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        struct timespec start, stop;
        unsigned long long res;
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &start);
        res = fib(i);
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &stop);
        timings[i] = ((stop.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) * 1e9 +
                      (stop.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec));
        printf(" %llu", res);
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("Time taken for each number:");
    for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        printf(" %.0fns", timings[i]);
        total_time += timings[i];
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("Total time: %.0fns\n", total_time);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Enter the number of elements: 20
Fibonacci Series: 0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144 233 377 610 987 1597 2584 4181 6765
Time taken for each number: 0ns 0ns 0ns 0ns 0ns 0ns 0ns 0ns 0ns 0ns 1000ns 0ns 1000ns 1000ns 2000ns 5000ns 6000ns 10000ns 18000ns 38000ns 69000ns
Total time: 151000ns
```

Comment: As I mentioned in a previous question by OP (now deleted) in the first example, the time for two `clock_gettime` calls far exceeds the time for the three assignments that we're trying to measure

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're using the clock on your main program which means it really as you said calculates the total runtime of the function.
in order to calculate how much time it took you to commit one sequence you should consider moving the

```
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &start);
```

And:

```
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &stop);
total_time = (stop.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) * 1e9;
total_time = (total_time + (stop.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec)) * 1e-9;
```

To the start and end of the printFibonacci , respectfully and in that case in each recursion you'll see the exact time it took a sequence to happen.